# How do I get all class properties by type?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, interface

How can I get all the properties of a class that implement a specific base class or interface?

I have a properties class that contains several other property classes. Some, not all, of these classes implement an interface. I would like to know if it's possible to iterate over all properties of parent class for child-classes that implement the target interface.

It sounds like a job for reflection? I'm just not sure how. Can it be done via the "PropertyInfo" object? Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) on the `PropertyInfo`'s `PropertyType`:

```
For Each prop In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
    If prop.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(GetType(YourInterface)) Then
        ' do something '
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. Can this method be used to detect properties that inherit from a base class? Probably my fault for not explaining the parameters correctly.